# How to generate number string in C#, "0" should not appear only 1-9 should appear in random String

Tags: c#, nunit

How to generate number string in C#, "0" should not appear only 1-9 should appear in random String

For random string mostly it appeared "0" but i dont want "0" in string i need vale from 1 - 9

Answer (score 1):

```
Random r = new();
string digits = "123456789";
string randomDigit = digits[r.Next(digits.Length)].ToString();
```